# opencv create map with Point as key

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to insert into a map where keys are `cv::Point`, values are bools. I am do so like the following:

```
Mat& pts = ...
std::map<cv::Point, bool>& myMap;
myMap.insert({pts.at<Point>(5), true});
```

But am getting 
`invalid operands to binary expression ('const cv::Point_<int>' and 'const cv::Point_<int>'){return __x < __y;}`

Note that i have defined the following for comparisons:

```
 bool operator<(cv::Point const& a, cv::Point const& b)
 {
     return (a.x < b.x) || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
 }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Even if I comment out
`myMap.insert({pts.at<Point>(5), true});` I have issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your `operator<` function, declare your comparator like this:

```
struct ComparePoints
{
    bool operator () (const cv::Point& a, const cv::Point& b) const
    { 
        return (a.x < b.x) || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
    }
};
```

And your map like this:

```
std::map <cv::Point, bool, ComparePoints> myMap;
```

Then it all works.